# Merging kubeconfig JSON and YAML

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubeconfig

I have two kubeconfigs file, the first one is following which I use to communicate with the cluster and the second one is for Aquasec which is in JSON format. How can I merge these two?

```
apiVersion: v1
    clusters:
    - cluster:
        certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
        server: https://656835E69F31E2933asdAFAKE3F5904sadFDDC112dsasa7.yld432.eu-west-2.eks.amazonaws.com
      name: arn:aws:eks:eu-west-2:test651666:cluster/Magento
    - cluster:
        certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
        server: https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443
      name: docker-desktop
    - cluster:
        certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
        server: https://192.142.242.111:6443
      name: kubernetes
    contexts:
    - context:
        cluster: arn:aws:eks:eu-west-2:test651666:cluster/testing
        user: arn:aws:eks:eu-west-2:test651666:cluster/testing
      name: arn:aws:eks:eu-west-2:test651666:cluster/testing
    - context:
        cluster: docker-desktop
        user: docker-desktop
      name: docker-desktop
    - context:
        cluster: docker-desktop
        user: docker-desktop
      name: docker-for-desktop
    - context:
        cluster: kubernetes
        user: kubernetes-admin
      name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
    current-context: arn:aws:eks:eu-west-2:test651666:cluster/testing
    kind: Config
    preferences: {}
    users:
    - name: arn:aws:eks:eu-west-2:test651666:cluster/testing
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the `KUBECONFIG` environment variable to multiple config files delimited by `:` and kubectl will automatically merge them behind the scenes.

For example:

```
export KUBECONFIG=config:my-config.json
```

In the export above, `config` is the default config file contained within `~/.kube` and `my-config.json` would be your second config file, which you said is in JSON format.

You can see the merged config using this command, which shows a unified view of the configuration that kubectl is currently using:

```
kubectl config view
```

Because kubectl automatically merges multiple configs, you shouldn't need to save the merged config to a file.  But if you really want to do that, you can redirect the output, like this:

```
kubectl config view --flatten > merged-config.yaml
```

Check out [Mastering the KUBECONFIG file](https://ahmet.im/blog/mastering-kubeconfig/), [Organizing Cluster Access Using kubeconfig Files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/) for more explanation and to see some other examples.